# A call to PInvoke function 'Test!DllCall::initDll' has unbalanced the stack

Tags: c#, java-native-interface, pinvoke

Bit of an unusual question.

I have worked out that the error is only thrown when running the program via visual studio. If I compile the application and run the compiled program it works fine. Any ideas what would cause this?

I have a C# class that calls a method in a Java DLL ( compiled through excelsior jet ) via JNI.

When I compile and run the C# class an an executable everything works fine. Now I have built the C# class as a DLL and am trying to call it from another class.

At this point I get the followign error message:
A call to PInvoke function 'Test!DllCall::initDll' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.

Could anyone explain why Im getting this and how to fix it?

Please let me know if you need anymore code/information

Heres the C# code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Text;

        public class DllCall
        {
            [DllImport("Stubs")]
            public static extern int  initDll(String userDllName);

            [DllImport("Stubs")]
            public static extern void finalizeDll();

            [DllImport("Stubs")]
            public static extern UInt32 newClassInstance();

            [DllImport("Stubs")]
            public static extern int  invokeStaticMethod();

            [DllImport("Stubs")]
            public static extern String  request(UInt32 hClassInst, String input);

            [DllImport("Stubs")]
            public static extern void  close();

            [DllImport("Stubs")]
            public static extern void  voidtest(UInt32 hClassInst);


        }


        public class Test
        {
            public UInt32 hClass;


            public Test()
            {
                    //when compiled as a DLL this line throws the error. 
                int rc = DllCall.initDll("dllClass.dll");
                Console.Write("---> initDll() rc = {0}\n", rc);

                hClass = DllCall.newClassInstance();
                Console.Write("---> hClass = {0}\n", hClass);
            }

            // When compiled as an executable this method runs fine.
            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                int rc = DllCall.initDll("dllClass.dll");
                string rs;
                Console.Write("---> initDll() rc = {0}\n", rc);

                UInt32 hClass = DllCall.newClassInstance();
                Console.Write("---> hClass = {0}\n", hClass);

                rs = DllCall.request(hClass, "moo");
                Console.Write("---> request() rs = {0}\n", rs);

                DllCall.close();

                DllCall.finalizeDll();
            }



            public string request( string xmlInput )
            {
                string rs;
                rs = DllCall.request(hClass, xmlInput);
                Console.Write("---> request() rs = {0}\n", rs);
                return rs;
            }

            public void finalizeDll()
            {
                DllCall.finalizeDll();
            }

            public void closeConnection()
            {
                DllCall.close();
            }
        }
```

I know this is a lot of code but as requested heres the code in the C Dll.....

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <windows.h>

JNIEnv  *env;
JavaVM  *jvm;
HANDLE  hUserDll;
jclass  jClass;
char*  dllname;

/*
 * Load dll.
 */
HANDLE loadDll(char* name)
{
    HANDLE hDll = LoadLibrary (name);

    if (!hDll) {
        printf ("Unable to load %s\n", name);
        exit(1);
    }

    printf ("%s loaded\n", name);

    return hDll;
}

jint (JNICALL * JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs_func) (void *args);
jint (JNICALL * JNI_CreateJavaVM_func) (JavaVM **pvm, void **penv, void *args);



/*
 * Initialize JET run-time.
 */
void initJavaRT(HANDLE myDllHandle, JavaVM** pjvm, JNIEnv** penv)
{
    int            result;
    JavaVMInitArgs args;

    JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs_func = 
             (jint (JNICALL *) (void *args))
             GetProcAddress (myDllHandle, "JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs");

    JNI_CreateJavaVM_func =
             (jint (JNICALL *) (JavaVM **pvm, void **penv, void *args))
             GetProcAddress (myDllHandle, "JNI_CreateJavaVM");

    if(!JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs_func) {
        printf ("%s doesn't contain public JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs\n", dllname);
        exit (1);
    }

    if(!JNI_CreateJavaVM_func) {
        printf ("%s doesn't contain public JNI_CreateJavaVM\n", dllname);
        exit (1);
    }

    memset (&args, 0, sizeof(args));
    args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_2;

    result = JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs_func(&args);
    if (result != JNI_OK) {
        printf ("JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs() failed with result %d\n", result);
        exit(1);
    }

    /*
     * NOTE: no JVM is actually created
     * this call to JNI_CreateJavaVM is intended for JET RT initialization
     */
    result = JNI_CreateJavaVM_func (pjvm, (void **)penv, &args);
    if (result != JNI_OK) {
        printf ("JNI_CreateJavaVM() failed with result %d\n", result);
        exit(1);
    }

    printf ("JET RT initialized\n");
    fflush (stdout);
}


/*
 * Look for class.
 */
jclass lookForClass (JNIEnv* env, char* name)
{
    jclass clazz = (*env)->FindClass (env, name);

    if (!clazz) {
        printf("Unable to find class %s\n", name);
        exit(1);
    }

    printf ("Class %s found\n", name);
    fflush (stdout);

    return clazz;
}


int initDll(char* userDllName) 
{
  jClass = NULL;
  hUserDll = loadDll(userDllName); 
  dllname = userDllName;
  initJavaRT(hUserDll, &jvm, &env); 
  jClass = lookForClass(env, "mooMain/mooGeminiX3/mooGeminiX3IFX");
  return jClass ? 1 : 0;
}

/** finalizeDll() - stop Java VM
 */
void finalizeDll ()
{
    (*jvm)->DestroyJavaVM (jvm);
    FreeLibrary((HMODULE)hUserDll);
    hUserDll = NULL;
    jClass   = NULL;
}


jobject newClassInstance()
{

    jmethodID MID_init;
    jobject obj;
    jstring name;
    jobjectArray ret;
    jclass sclass;
    jobjectArray arr;

    MID_init = (*env)->GetMethodID (env, jClass, "<init>", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");
    if (!MID_init) {
        printf("Error: dllClass.<init>() not found\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    sclass = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/String");
    arr = (*env)->NewObjectArray(env, 6, sclass, NULL);


    name = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"@C:\\Users\\Ash\\Desktop\\moo-Test\\moo-Test\\mooRoot.cfg");
    (*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env,arr,0,name);  
    name = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"-cfg");
    (*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env,arr,1,name);
    name = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"C:\\Users\\Ash\\Desktop\\moo-CVS\\moo-PCB\\Application\\Configuration\\Linear\\Application\\moo.cfg");
    (*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env,arr,2,name);
    name = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"-startupLog");
    (*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env,arr,3,name);  
    name = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"C:\\Users\\Ash\\Desktop\\moo-Test\\moo-Test\\Log\\mooStartup.log"); 
    (*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env,arr,4,name);
    name = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"-geminiX3"); 
    (*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env,arr,5,name);












    obj = (*env)->NewObject(env, jClass, MID_init, arr);
    if (!obj) {
        printf("Error: failed to allocate an object\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    return obj;
}

const char* request(jobject obj, char* input )
{
    jstring inputString;
    jstring outputString;
    const char *nativeString;


    jmethodID mID = (*env)->GetMethodID (env, jClass, "request", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;");
    if (!mID){
        printf("\nError: dllClass.request() not found\n");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("here"); fflush(stdout);
    inputString = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, input);
    printf("here2"); fflush(stdout);

    outputString = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, obj, mID, inputString);    

    nativeString = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, outputString, 0); 


    return nativeString;
}

void voidtest(jobject obj )
{/*
    jmethodID mID = (*env)->GetMethodID (env, jClass, "request", "([Ljava/lang/String;)[Ljava/lang/String;");

    if (!mID){
        printf("\nError: dllClass.request() not found\n");
        return 0;
    }

    char inputString[] = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Moo");

    (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, obj, mID, inputString);*/
}   

void close()
{
    jmethodID mID = (*env)->GetMethodID (env, jClass, "close", "()V");
    if (!mID){
        printf("\nError: dllClass.close() not found\n");
    }

    (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env,jClass, mID);
}


int invokeStaticMethod()
{
    jmethodID MID_init;
    jobject obj;
    jstring name;
    jobjectArray ret;
    jclass sclass;
    jobjectArray arr;
    jmethodID mID = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, jClass, "start", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");

    if (!mID){
        printf("\nError: dllClass.sfstart() not found\n");
        return 0;
    }

    sclass = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/String");
    arr = (*env)->NewObjectArray(env, 5, sclass, NULL);


    name = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"@C:\\Users\\Ash\\Desktop\\moo-Test\\moo-Test\\mooRoot.cfg");
    (*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env,arr,0,name);  
    name = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"-cfg");
    (*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env,arr,1,name);
    name = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"C:\\Users\\Ash\\Desktop\\moo-CVS\\moo-PCB\\Application\\Configuration\\Linear\\Application\\moo.cfg");
    (*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env,arr,2,name);
    name = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"-startupLog");
    (*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env,arr,3,name);  
    name = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"C:\\Users\\Ash\\Desktop\\moo-Test\\moo-Test\\Log\\mooStartup.log"); 
    (*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env,arr,4,name);



    (*env)->CallStaticVoidMethod(env,jClass, mID, arr);
    printf("\nGot to here\n");

    return 1;
}
```

Kind Regards

Ash

Comment: Java, C#, JNI, and P/Invoke all in one question?  You are a masochist.  Show the header file produced by the JNI tool.

Comment: Hi Ben as far as I know I dont have a file like that. I have added the C file above. As I mentioned I am just starting out with all this so sorry If I seem stupid.

Comment: I have worked out that the error is only thrown when running the program via visual studio. If I compile the application and run the compiled program it works fine. Any ideas what would cause this?

Answer (score 6):

This usually happens when you have an incorrect parameter list or mismatching calling convention.

You really ought to know what calling convention the other DLL is. If it is `cdecl` then you change your P/invoke to:

```
[DllImport("Stubs", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
```

You need to do this for all imports.

The other thing to check is that your parameter lists match. You only showed one side of the boundary so we can't check that for you. If you added the other side then we may be able to spot something.

---

**Updated following addition of C code**

I have the following comments on your code:

The parameters for the C# declaration of `initDll` match the C declaration so I'm pretty confident that the issue is that your C code uses `cdecl` calling convention. The C# P/invoke defaults to `stdcall`. Change the calling convention in one or the other, but not both!

You are matching `jobject` with `UInt32`. I'm not sure about this since I don't know JNI. However, I suspect you should be returning `jobject*` and matching with `IntPtr`. It looks to me as though `jobject` is a class type and not something that you can marshal to C#.

Finally, one of your methods returns a `string`. That just won't work. The C# marshaller will attempt to deallocate it with a call to `CoTaskMemFree`. That will leak or bomb, dependent on which Windows version you have. You should return an `IntPtr` and use `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi` to marshal it into a C# string. Then you need to deallocate the memory returned by the JNI code. Not sure how you plan to do that. Of course, if your strings are really UTF-8 then you would need to copy to a byte array and then use Encoding.UTF8 to convert to a C# string.

Comment: I've edited the OP to show the code in the C file. By the way I know very little about this area so please forgive me If I seem obtuse :)

Comment: One thing to highlight is that this code does seem to work when I run the test method found in the C# test class, the issue arises when I try to instansiate a test object and call any of the methods in the test class on it.

Comment: I made a comment about your matching of `jobject` with `UInt32`. Do you have a definition for `jobject` at hand. `UInt32` is surely wrong.

Comment: I have worked out that the error is only thrown when running the program via visual studio. If I compile the application and run the compiled program it works fine. Any ideas what would cause this?

Comment: Yes. The debug assistant that tells you your stack is imbalanced only runs under debug. The stack is still imbalanced. Did you change calling convention? Why are you ignoring my other questions. Hard to help with one way flow of information.

Comment: Sorry David, I'll try and do what you suggest. Im having a hard time understanding why the compiled program still seems to work with an unbalanced stack. I will try and change the calling convention in C# to cdecl and let you know how that goes. As I said I am modfying an example here so only just learning all this stuff....

Comment: P/invoke marshaller is resilient to abuses of the stack. But you should still get the calling convention right. Once you've done that you need to address the `jobject` issue.